# History of calendar of different culture

Tags: cultural-history, calendar

Why in almost every calendar of different culture, a week consists of seven days? Are there any link between different calendars?

Comment: What isn't covered in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ancient Greeks and Egyptians had a week of 10 days, the Ancient Romans of 9, the Aztecs of 5 days, the Ancient Japanese of 6, the Ancient Chinese week went from 9 to 12 days...

The Babylonians started the week of 7 days, pairing the "planets" they could see (Sun, Moon, Mercury, Venus, Mars, Jupiter and Saturn) to the lunar month of 29 days. So they made it 4x7= 28 days and at the end of the year they had special weeks longer than 7 days.

Comment: Sources would greatly improve this answer.